# Dealing with view implicit acquisition problems in Plone

Tags: plone

In Plone adding a member variable in a view class instance automatically makes it a part of view acquisition chain. The problem is described in detail here:

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views/browserviews.html#views-and-automatic-member-variable-acquisition-wrapping

What is the suggested approach for dealing with this problem

- Can we have Plone main template based views without implicit acquisition
- How about viewlets and portlet renderers then?
- If not... how one should deal with the problem so that self.xxx variables do not get extra acquisition wrapping?

Comment: What view class are you using? As of Zope 2.12 Products.Five.BrowserView no longer subclasses Acquisition.Explicit so I don't think this should happen. But maybe you're using another view class, or maybe I'm forgetting something...

Comment: Does the same apply for viewlets and portlets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Acquisition.aq_inner()` to strip away the extra wrapping and restore the object to it's original path. Please, do not use the single-item list approach as described in the document you link to.

To show one example from the linked document, but corrected with `aq_inner()`:

```
from Acquisition import aq_inner

self.obj = self.context.reference_catalog.lookupObject(value)
return aq_inner(self.obj).absolute_url() # Acquistion chain corrected
```

Alternatively, you can use the `aq_inner` attribute:

```
self.obj = self.context.reference_catalog.lookupObject(value)
return self.obj.aq_inner.absolute_url() # Acquistion chain corrected
```

but that only works on objects that inherit from `Acquisition.Explicit` or `Acquisition.Implicit`; the `aq_inner()` function returns the passed argument verbatim if it is not a Acquisition-wrapped object.

Comment: Updated the docs. Thanks! I knew there had to be a better way. The list approach was used in some Plone coreish add-on.